# What is the plural form of the word "Demiurge"

Tags: grammatical-number

What would be the plural form of the word "Demiurge", (the Creator~).

**One Demiurge.**

**Many Demiurges?**

Comment: Note that unless used as a proper noun, it need not be capitalized.

Comment: I am using it as a synonyme to the word - "Creator" (of the world). The troubling part was how would you say, "Other Creators <...>" I was not sure if it would be Demiurges or some other irregular form, google translate gave me four versions of one word...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dictionaries I've checked don't give a plural form, which means that they think the plural is formed regularly, i.e., *demiurges*.

However, all three possible plurals, the English plural [*demiurges*](http://books.google.com/books?id=SaAHAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA154&dq=demiurges&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ldYSUvfuKdPe4AOQ0oCYBA&ved=0CFAQ6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=demiurges&f=false), the Latin plural [*demiurgi*](http://books.google.com/books?id=Jumamrx5UgoC&pg=PA52&dq=demiurgi&hl=en&sa=X&ei=yNUSUtbQHrTJ4APJhoHoAQ&ved=0CCwQ6AEwADiOAg#v=onepage&q=demiurgi&f=false), and the Greek plural [*demiurgoi*](http://books.google.com/books?id=xs0WAQAAIAAJ&pg=PA216&dq=demiurgoi&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ZNYSUo-aFrHD4APeg4GIDA&ved=0CEIQ6AEwBDgK#v=onepage&q=demiurgoi&f=false), seem to have been used in English. If for some reason you don't like using *demiurges*, you have good precedents to justify this decision.

Comment: Thank you, I was not sure if it was Demiurges or if it had an irregular form, google translate was messing with me. :)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, demiurges. It's from Latin demiurgus, but is clearly not a Latin form now, so the plural is standard for English.

Comment: It is [actually](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=demiurge=) from the Greek _δημιουργός_ which was later latinized so I guess if you were to be pedantic, you would use the Greek plural and write _demiourgoi_.

Comment: I absolutely do not agree that you could use Greek plural or a Latin one (demiurgi, anyone?) since the singular in English is not a Greek or Latin word. It would be pretentious to do either. Since the Greek-ness of the original word is irrelevant, I didn't mention it.